# UK Visa refusal due to other refusals

Tags: working-visas, france, uk-visa, refusal, skilled-migration

Is there anyone whose UK visa was refused due to his/her past visa refusal of Schengen or other countries? In Dec 2022, my French visa was refused on basis of "risk to public security/public order/public health". Although I have no criminal record and have never been in the Schengen area and have already appealed against the refusal, but yet there is no response from French authorities.

Soon I am going to apply for UK skilled work visa and this refusal can impact my UK visa application. My French immigration consultant (who prepared my appeal for French court) suggested that I locate any such case in which UK visa was refused based on Schengen/third country visa refusal. As one of my argument in French court is to annul French visa refusal as this will impact my UK visa application. I am already in contact with few UK immigration solicitors to look for such cases.If there is anyone who had such situation in past please let me know.

Comment: I have edited the text of your title and question for clarity, and I have tried to keep your questions and concerns unchanged. If you disagree with my changes, you can roll back the changes so your original wording reappears.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica thank you for editing. It looks good 

Comment: I know this isn't an answer and since I am new here, I cannot comment. But I am also kinda in a similar situation. My French student visa also got rejected for the same reason. Did you apply for your UK work visa? Any updates? I'm sorry to ask my question in the form of answer. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It is actually the task of your French immigration consultant to locate any such cases to use on your behalf. Your french visa refusal can only be annulled if the reasons for the refusal have been found to be false. The fact that this refusal will effect other applications **plays no role** in any visa refusal annulment. Get another immigration consultant would be my advice.

Comment: The UK will know about the refusal. So if you lie about it and say you've never been refused a visa, they know and it's game over. If you tell them (and they know anyway) they will look at the reason for the refusal. There may be reasons that they don't care about, there may be reasons based on your personal situation that could go away over time because your situations changed, so they will check that. There may be reasons where they say "if France refused a visa for this reason, then we refuse it as well".

Comment: @Akash very sorry to know that you facing the similar situation. I have appealed against the French refusal but it has been refused by commission and now appeal is in administrative court. Same suggestion is to you if you want to annul the decision and remove the refusal from your record.I have to apply for UK visa soon.

Comment: @gnasher729 UK can refuse if it's just been refused by France or they'll look into my record and see if the basis of such refusal is right or not? I have no intentions to hide the refusal but still unsure how much information I should share?

Comment: (I'll raise a flag to convert this answer into a comment. Moderators, please help. Sorry in advance) @Stark Sorry to hear that. Hope, appeal in the administrative court goes in your favor. Did you get a reply from the commission stating the refusal or you did not get any reply for 2 months making it an automatic rejection? If you did get a reply from the commission, how long did it take for them to reply from the day you sent the appeal and what reason did they give your refusal?
It'll be really helpful if you could give some details as I am also planning on lodging an appeal.